# acmart: problem generating the union symbol - math environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, amsmath, inline

I am trying to use the Union symbol in an acmart document. I tried using `\bigcup_{lower}^{upper} value` command to generate the union symbol but Latex leaves an empty space for the `U` symbol. The same is happening for other symbols also (Sigma for summing over a series). I have included the `asmath` package and the document compiles also, the only problem is that the symbols are not displayed.
Any help on how I can get these symbols inline?

Comment: Please provide a short complete document code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A simple `\documentclass{acmart}\begin{document}\[\bigcup_{0}^1\]\end{document}` shows the symbol.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! I had already used this command but the problem was `lmodern` package that I had included in my document. Turns out there was some conflict caused because of that. I removed this package and the code compiles fine, and the symbols appear fine too! 
Thanks again

Comment: @BajajG As far as I know, `acmart` uses by default Linux Libertine; since it is intended for submissions to journals or conferences, one should not use font packages with it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about this. I had some JSON text and C++ code that I wanted to include so I used a few font packages - `fontenc`, `listings`, and `lmodern`. I hope the other two don't cause further problems.

Answer (score 4):

The `acmart` class does

```
\newif\if@ACM@newfonts
\@ACM@newfontstrue
\IfFileExists{libertine.sty}{}{\ClassWarning{\@classname}{You do not
    have libertine package installed.  Please upgrade your
    TeX}\@ACM@newfontsfalse}
\IfFileExists{zi4.sty}{}{\ClassWarning{\@classname}{You do not
    have zi4 package installed.  Please upgrade your TeX}\@ACM@newfontsfalse}
\IfFileExists{newtxmath.sty}{}{\ClassWarning{\@classname}{You do not
    have newtxmath package installed.  Please upgrade your
    TeX}\@ACM@newfontsfalse}
\if@ACM@newfonts
\RequirePackage[tt=false]{libertine}
\RequirePackage[varqu]{zi4}
\RequirePackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
```

This means that the class wants to use Linux Libertine for standard text, the `newtxmath` fonts adapted to Libertine for math and Inconsolata (`zi4`) for the monospaced font. It resorts to the default LaTeX fonts only if the local TeX system doesn't have the necessary resources.

The class also selects the T1 output font encoding (unless the system is defective). It always loads `amsmath`.

If we do

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}

\show\bigcup
\show\bigcupop

\[\bigcup\]

\end{document}
```

we get, on the terminal,

```
> \bigcup=macro:
->\DOTSI \bigcupop \slimits@ .

> \bigcupop=\mathchar"13D0.
```

If we also add `lmodern`, the output would be the same, but the log file would contain the message

```
Missing character: There is no <D0> in font lmex10!
```

This is because `newtxmath` sets as font for large symbols one that uses the `LMX` encoding, which is different from the encoding used by `lmodern`, which assumes the standard encodings for math fonts.

Here's the problem: `newtxmath` defines `\bigcupop` to be in the large symbol fonts (the `3` in the mathcode above) at position `D0`. When `lmodern` is loaded, it doesn't reset the correspondence symbol-slot and so nothing is typeset, because the large symbols font used by `lmodern` has nothing at that position.

The conclusion is

> when using `acmart` don't load *any* font package that sets the text fonts or the standard math fonts.

Additional math symbol fonts (for instance `stmaryrd`) that augment the set of math symbols available may be used, but beware that they could clash with the main fonts. As another example, `amssymb` should not be loaded, because `newtxmath` already covers it.